# How to get rid of gradient shading on the bottom of grass

Tags: unity, rendering, ambient-occlusion

I've been using Unity's terrain system and a Vegetation Spawner asset (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/vegetation-spawner-177192) to make some terrain for my game. While using the Flooded Grounds (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/flooded-grounds-48529) grass meshes for the grass, I've stumbled upon an issue with how the grass is colored. As seen in the attached picture, the bottom of the grass blades is black, the tips are the desired color, and everything in between is a gradient between the two colors. I've tried everything I could from changing material properties to editing and disabling lighting/shadows and post processing effects like ambient occlusion, all to no avail. The grass material doesn't seem to be shaded in this manner, but when the grass prefab is placed with or without the vegetation spawner, I get this effect, even in a new project. How can I just have the grass be one solid color with no gradient?

[image: Shading underneath grass mesh]

Answer (score 0):

This effect is not coming from the Unity terrain. It is most likely coming from your vegetation spawner or flooded grounds asset. Look into the settings for those assets.